# Not able to call a method by using 'this' keyword inside another method from a same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass an alert after the user submits a form. The html is like this

```
<form id="profile" name="profile">
  <label for="firstName">Male</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstName" maxlength="20" class="required" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" name="sumit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And the JS is

```
var Form = function(){}; 

Form.prototype.formValidate = function($form){

    $form.on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.test()// this doesn't work
    //alert('t') // this works
  })

}

Form.prototype.test = function(){
    alert('t');
}
var form = new Form();
form.formValidate($('#profile'))
```

When I am getting an error saying ..this.test is not a function...
If I just pass the alert right after the e.preventDefault() but it cant call I cant call a method by a keyword 'this'. Which makes me say my scope is not right. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, the value of `this` is based on scope.  Every time you have `function(){}`, then you have a *new* scope.  Inside each function, `this` is going to be different, it's set based on how that function is *called*.

Where you are doing `this.test()`, `this` is not the `Form` object, it's the `#profile` element.  You'll need to save the `this` value into a variable so you can use it in the event.

```
Form.prototype.formValidate = function($form){
    var self = this;

    $form.on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        self.test();
    });
};
```

Comment: Right..I could call it just fine outside the $form.on()

Comment: @soum: Exactly, because then you were inside a function on the `Form` object.  Once you're inside the event, you are in a new context and `this` has changed.  That's why you need to *save* it as a variable then access that variable inside the event.